# Could not deploy business network to hyperledger fabric beta using composer

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I have tried to deploy a business network using composer to but it fails with the following error

> Error: event message must be properly signed by an identity from the same organization as the peer: [Expected MSP ID Org1MSP, received ]]

what is the problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several reasons why you might get this error

1. You are not running composer v0.8.0 or higher. You can check what level you are running by invoking the command

> composer -v

2. You haven't specified a valid hlfv1 profile or you forgot to specify the profile to use on the network deploy command. If you have followed the tutorials and guides on the hyperledger composer site then a profile will have been created called **hlfv1**. Ensure you specify it on the command line invocations. For example to deploy

> composer network deploy -a test.bna -i PeerAdmin -s anything -p hlfv1

Answer (score -1):

You are running an older version of docker.  Level may be checked by invoking the command: `docker -v`

Invoking the `./prereqs-ubuntu.sh` detailed in the 'Installing a developing with Hyperledger Composer' will update the prerequisites accordingly.

Comment: The error that this would give is
'Error: error trying deploy. Error: Failed to deserialize creator identity, err MSP Org1MSP is unknown'
rather than the one described in this question. There is another SO entry for this specific problem