# Fabric composer demo Error on Mac

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I have followed the instructions composer/tutorials/developer-guide.html and after testing my business network on playground, I am getting the following error message when I am trying to deploy my business network on Fabric.

```
composer network deploy -a my-network.bna -p hlfv1 -i PeerAdmin -s randomString
```

:: output

```
Deploying business network from archive: my-network.bna
Business network definition:
    Identifier: my-network@0.0.1
    Description: My very first Hyperledger Composer Network

events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: event message must be properly signed by an identity from the same organization as the peer: [failed deserializing event creator: [Expected MSP ID Org1MSP, received ]]
    at ClientDuplexStream._emitStatusIfDone (/Users/reza/.nvm/versions/node/v6.10.3/lib/node_modules/composer-cli/node_modules/fabric-client/node_modules/grpc/src/node/src/client.js:201:19)
    at ClientDuplexStream._receiveStatus (/Users/reza/.nvm/versions/node/v6.10.3/lib/node_modules/composer-cli/node_modules/fabric-client/node_modules/grpc/src/node/src/client.js:180:8)
    at /Users/reza/.nvm/versions/node/v6.10.3/lib/node_modules/composer-cli/[enter image description here][1]node_modules/fabric-client/node_modules/grpc/src/node/src/client.js:649:14
```

[Docker Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xVY5f.png)

I couldn't go further than this.

My environment settings are:

```
node -v
v6.10.3
```

---

```
npm -v
3.10.10
```

---

```
composer -v
composer-cli                   v0.7.5
composer-admin                 v0.7.5
composer-client                v0.7.5
composer-common                v0.7.5
composer-runtime-hlfv1         v0.7.5
```

---

```
docker -v
Docker version 17.06.0-ce-rc4, build 29fcd5d
```

Please let me know what I am missing ?

Comment: This is a duplicate of
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44595831/could-not-deploy-business-network-to-hyperledger-fabric-beta-using-composer
you need to upgrade to composer 0.8.0

Answer (score 2):

As david_k says, this is a duplicate of:

[Could not deploy business network to hyperledger fabric beta using composer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44595831/could-not-deploy-business-network-to-hyperledger-fabric-beta-using-composer)

You must upgrade your level of Hyperledger Composer to v0.8.0 or greater in order to use Hyperledger Fabric v1.0 beta.