# Error creating hyperledger composer rest server

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I got the following error:

```
"Error: event message must be properly signed by an identity from the same organization as the peer: [failed deserializing event creator: [Expected MSP ID Org1MSP, received ]]"
```

When I execute:

> composer-rest-server

Similar to : 
[Could not deploy business network to hyperledger fabric beta using composer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44595831/could-not-deploy-business-network-to-hyperledger-fabric-beta-using-composer)

But this is on rest server and I have the correct versions:

```
    composer -v
    composer-cli                   v0.8.0
    composer-admin                 v0.8.0
    composer-client                v0.8.0
    composer-common                v0.8.0
    composer-runtime-hlf           v0.8.0
    composer-runtime-hlfv1         v0.8.0

    docker -v
    Docker version 17.03.1-ce, build c6d412e
    docker-compose -v
    docker-compose version 1.13.0, build 1719ceb
    npm -v
    3.10.10
```

Hypeledger running with my model:

```
composer network ping -n calma-network -p hlfv1 -i admin -s adminpw
The connection to the network was successfully tested: calma-network
        version: 0.8.0
        participant: <no participant found>

Command succeeded
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command you entered only shows the version of the composer command line interface and doesn't include the version of the composer rest server. The composer rest server is standalone and doesn't require the composer cli to run. It is highly likely your composer rest server is older than version 0.8.0 but there is no easy way to check the version. One way is to invoke the command

> npm list -g --depth=0 | grep composer-rest-server

you need to uninstall and reinstall the composer rest server to get the latest level.

Comment: You were completely right . I was using 0.7 version of composer rest server, now with 0.8 its OK. Thank you.